# Apache Nutch Crawl Dynamic Products

Tags: solr, nutch, web-crawler, sitemap.xml

Currently we are using Apache Solr as Search Engine and Apache Nutch as Crawler. Now we have created a site site which contains products which gets generated dynamically.

As current setup will search the content within content field, so whenever we are searching for dynamic Product, then its not coming in search results.

Can you please guide me how to crawl and index Dynamic Product on a Page to Apache Solr? Can we do this using Sitemap.xml, If yes then please suggest how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is this:

Step 1) Put the description of each dynamic product in its own page. e.g `http://domain/product?id=xxx` (or with more friendly url such as `http://domain/product-x`).

Step 2) You need a page or several pages that list urls of these products. The sitemap.xml you mentioned is one choice but a simple html page is also suffice. So, for instance, you can dynamically generate a page named products_list which contains entries like this: `<a href="http://domain/product?id=xxx">Product x</a>`.

Step 3) You should either add url of products_list page to your nutch seed file or include a link to it in one of already crawling pages.

Comment: Actually, Dynamic product don't have url itself. Thay got fetched using AJAX call.

Below is an example. Here you can different products. Please guide how I crawl and index these in Apache Solr.

http://www-hk.mcdonalds.com/hk/en/food/a-la-carte-explorer-view/burgers-explorer-view.html

When you click on List View, You will get Product List in List and URL will be as below :
http://www-hk.mcdonalds.com/hk/en/food/a-la-carte-list-view/burgers-list-view.html

Thanks!

Comment: Ok this is harder than I thought. For ajax calls you should look for its target. For example, in this specific site, it actually reads its list from this url using an ajax call: `http://www-hk.mcdonalds.com/content/hk/en/food/a-la-carte-list-view/burgers-list-view.hk_nutri.list.6|7|8|9|10|11|.en.html`. So you should introduce this url to nutch. Also, since you don't have separate page for each product, you need to write a nutch plugin (an HtmlParseFilter plugin) to parse this page and in that plugin produce multiple documents.

Comment: I don't have much experience on java. Can you please help me with new document or link? Also, is there inbuilt configuration available within nutch to accomplish above requirements. I mean is it possible to do this by making configuration level changes.

Currently I am using Nutch Versio 1.6!